# Python dynamic attribute value bind to method

Tags: python, python-2.7, dynamic-attributes

after reading several posts here I am still a bit confused on the correct way to implement a Class dynamic attribute with a function as value.

Been some time since I touched python and now I am a bit stuck.

I have the following class:

```
class RunkeeperUser(object):

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        # Get the user methods and set the attributes
        for user_method, call in self.master.query('user').iteritems():
            # Should not get the value but bind a method
            setattr(
                self,
                user_method,
                self.master.query(call)
            )

    def get_user_id(self):
        return self.user_id


    def query(self, call):
        return self.master(call)
```

Right now as you can see when setting the attribute it directly executes the self.master.query(call) and already results are there when the attribute is accessed.

The question is how can I make this attribute value dynamic upon runtime and not already executed?

I have tried:

```
setattr(
                self,
                user_method,
                lambda: self.master.query(call)
            )
```

But that does not work well for some reason. Any help/guidance or best principals to achieve the described result?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "does not work well"? Does the function not get called? Do you get an exception and, if so, what is the traceback?

Comment: @user4815162342 Doesn't contain the correct result. I think it contains something irrelevant from the 1st exmaple. It's an api call, so the 1st implementation if I do eg: ```user.profile``` works ok and has the correct data but using the lambda it posts the last dict call or so. I am confused as well. Sorry.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Funny must be it. Also with runkeeper. Thanks checking asap and reporting

Comment: Yes dup. Please close this question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a well known gotcha. You have to bind your argument's current value in the lambda, ie:

```
setattr(
        self,
        user_method,
        lambda call=call: self.master.query(call)
        )
```